# NuGet, Packages.config, .csproj and references

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, packages.config

I have a question so that I can better understand `NuGet` packages, `packages.config` and the `.csproj` file.

It is my understanding that the setting in the NuGet Package Manager >> General  for default package management format determines if your project uses `packages.config` or the `.csproj` file for resolving and restoring packages.
In my project we have selected Packages.config.

No problem  it compiles and runs. So I decided to test if it would run without the  reference for a `dll` in the `.csproj` file, as it is my understanding it does not use or need this. This is an incorrect assumption as though the package is in the `packages.config` file, when I removed the reference in the `.csproj` file there was an error in my project and the project would not compile.

I also noticed that if the `dll` is not in the references in the `Solution Explorer` that it fails to compile as well I( I assume these are the `.csproj` references).

So I am not clear on the role of the `.csproj` file for a `Packages.config` Management format for `NuGet` packages and the references in `Solution Explorer`.

Comment: To be 100% clear: Are you talking about .NET Framework or .NET Standard/Core?

Comment: When you add a Nuget Package reference to the project, Packages.config is modified to show update the list of Nuget packages being used by the project and .csproj file is modified to add the path of the library belonging to the package. So if you manually  modify the .csproj file and remove the DLL reference it will surly break because having entry in packages.config is different then having reference added to the .csproj file. The Nuget package my have multiple libraries targetting different .NET framework so when you add package .csproj file will have appropriate library referenced.

Comment: @john It is .Net  Framework

Comment: So my next question is why does Nuget when I restore packages not add an entry in references in .csproj file? Is that just a glitch that happens sometimes?

Comment: I just edited last comment to *not

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya would you like to post your comment as an answer

Comment: just ran into this as well, super confusing. makes you appreciate npm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is on how you manage your NuGet references.

Before VS2017 the information what NuGet packages to be used during assembly was stored in files packages.config.

Since VS2017 there is a new option called package references which stores this information in the project (.csproj) file.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference/

Answer (score 8):

**Before VS2017 and .NET Core**, NuGet was not deeply integrated into MSBuild so it needed a separate mechanism to list dependencies in a project: `packages.config` or `project.json`. Using Visual Studio solution explorer's References context menu, developer adds `.csproj` references to restored packages in a solution-wide folder managed by NuGet.

The reference added to the project file `.csproj` by Visual Studio looks like this:

`<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0"><HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath></Reference>`

**Starting with VS2017 and .NET Core**, NuGet becomes a first class citizen in MSBuild. NuGet package dependencies are now listed as PackageReference in the SDK-style project file `.csproj`

A reference now looks like this:

`<PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.4.4" />`

Comment: `developer manually integrates MSBuild` Can you add a code snippet example of this?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson updated answer with sample snippets. There is no C# code involved here because MSBuild uses XML to describe a C# project.